# toLowerCase(). need help understanding this in a more real world way

Tags: javascript, string, locale

```js
console.log('ALPHABET'.toLocaleLowerCase());

console.log('\u0130'.toLocaleLowerCase('tr') === 'i');
console.log('\u0130'.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US') === 'i');

let locales = ['tr', 'TR', 'tr-TR', 'tr-u-co-search', 'tr-x-turkish'];
console.log('\u0130'.toLocaleLowerCase(locales) === 'i');
```

Comment: A code dump isn't really much of a question. What specifically are you trying to get clarification on here? I'd suggest updating your question to include a clear problem statement. Consider checking out [ask] and the [tour] if you haven't yet.

Comment: This comes from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase

Comment: Question title says `toLowerCase()`, example code says `toLocaleLowerCase()`  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [String.prototype.toLocaleLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase):

> *The locale parameter indicates the locale to be used to convert to lower case according to any locale-specific case mappings. If multiple locales are given in an Array, the best available locale is used. The default locale is the host environment’s current locale*

Simply put, the value returned by the different locales may visually appear the same, but their values are different. Please take a look at my javascript below. I have converted the values to the provided locales and converted them back to Unicode so you may see what their actual values are.

Hope this helps,

```js
/* Helper function to display unicode value of a string 
http://buildingonmud.blogspot.com/2009/06/convert-string-to-unicode-in-javascript.html
*/
toUnicode = theString => {
  var unicodeString = '';
  [...theString].forEach((c, i) => {
    var theUnicode = c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
      theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
    }
    theUnicode = '\\u' + theUnicode;
    unicodeString += theUnicode;
  });
  return unicodeString;
}

// Unicode value of 'i'
console.log(`Unicode value of 'i': '${toUnicode('i')}'`);

//'tr': Unicode value: '\u0069'
console.log(`Unicode value for 'tr': '${toUnicode('\u0130'.toLocaleLowerCase('tr'))}'`);

// 'en-US': Unicode value: '\u0069\u0307'
console.log(`Unicode value for 'en-US': '${toUnicode('\u0130'.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US'))}'`);

let locales = ['tr', 'TR', 'tr-TR', 'tr-u-co-search', 'tr-x-turkish'];
console.log(`Unicode value for locales: '${toUnicode('\u0130'.toLocaleLowerCase(locales))}'`);
```